# Do I need to use glMapRange with buffer orphaning to avoid stalls?

Tags: performance, opengl, opengl-es-2.0

I've been told that buffer orphaning (i.e. calling `glBufferData()` with `NULL` for the final arg) allows us to avoid stalls that occur if GPU is trying to read a buffer object while CPU is trying to write to it.

What I'm not clear on is whether we can use this approach *without* `glMapBuffer*()`, or whether `glMapBuffer*()` is integral to the idea of orphaning and stall avoidance? I ask this purely to avoid making unnecessary changes to an existing codebase, though I understand `glMapBuffer*()` to be an inherently better choice than repeated `glBufferData()` in the long run.

(Please respond specific to OpenGL ES 2.0, unless the answer is general across GL versions.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was in the [official location](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Buffer_Object_Streaming):

> The first way is to call glBufferData​ with a NULL pointer, and the
>   exact same size and usage hints it had before. This allows the
>   implementation to simply reallocate storage for that buffer object
>   under-the-hood. Since allocating storage is (likely) faster than the
>   implicit synchronization, you gain significant performance advantages
>   over synchronization. And since you passed NULL, if there wasn't a
>   need for synchronization to begin with, this can be reduced to a
>   no-op. The old storage will still be used by the OpenGL commands that
>   have been sent previously. If you continue to use the same size
>   over-and-over, it is likely that the GL driver will not be doing any
>   allocation at all, but will just be pulling an old free block off the
>   unused buffer queue and use it (though of course this isn't
>   guaranteed), so it is likely to be very efficient.
>
> You can do the same thing when using glMapBufferRange​ with the
>   GL_MAP_INVALIDATE_BUFFER_BIT. You can also use
>   glInvalidateBufferData​, where available.

So I suppose it's safe to assume that only `glBufferData()` calls are needed for orphaning.